# Microsoft Bot framework bot with a RSS feed

Tags: botframework

I am looking to create a bot that uses an RSS feed as its source then use LUIS dialog questions to get information from it.

Comment: That's a great!  What code are you using to get your RSS feed?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I want to know is it possible to use a RSS feed as data source for a bot.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use LUIS to enable plain language questions and use an RSS feed to provide answers.

Answer (score 0):

LUIS dialog recognition is a service to provide better match of user intents. It does not take "data source".  To be able to use RSS data as data source as responds of a bot, You need to first passing in users' inputs into LUIS, in return, taking the match result and map to the answer you want onto the RSS data you desire.

Please take a look at https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/IntentDialog/#entity-recognition in the (Entity Recognition) section.